# If two groups are isomorphic to subgroups of each other, are they isomorphic themselves?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Suppose we have two groups, $G,H$ and that $\rho:G\rightarrow H, \tau:H\rightarrow  G$ are $1-1$ morphisms. Is it true then that $G,H$ are isomorphic? I don't think so, but I can't come up with any counter-example. This definitely holds for finite groups obviously. But what about infinite groups? Moreover, if it doesn't hold in general, does it hold for some large class of groups?

Comment: A group is *coHopfian* if it is not isomorphic to a subgroup of itself. If either of $G$ or $H$ is then it is true that $G\cong H$. One-ended hyperbolic groups are coHopfian, and indeed "almost all" groups are coHopfian (where "almost all" has a specific meaning, defined by Gromov).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One counterexample: the free group on two letters contains a subgroup isomorphic to the free group on three letters. (see here: [Show that the free group on three generators is a subgroup of the free group on two generators](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3123098/show-that-the-free-group-on-three-generators-is-a-subgroup-of-the-free-group-on/3139632))